# Does there exist a general formula for integrating the reciprocal of a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let $P$ be an arbitrary polynomial with real coefficients of degree greater than or equal to $1$. Then assuming $P$ does not have roots of multiplicity greater than $1$, I have arrived at the following formula using partial fraction decomposition and factoring completely over the splitting field:

$$\int \frac{1}{P(x)} dx = \sum\limits_{k: P(k)=0} \frac{\log(x-k)}{P'(k)}$$

It's strange to me however, that this fails in the case of $P'(k)$ being $0$ (multiple root). Is there a general formula for integrating the reciprocal of a general polynomial that encompasses all cases?

As a side note, when factoring completely to perform the integral, how can we show that the computed result is real even if the formula contains complex numbers?

Comment: Why not partial fraction decomposition directly?

Comment: Partial fractions would require more terms with repeated root, so of course it will be different.

Comment: It’s worth consider the power series of $\frac1{P(x)}$ when $P(0)\neq 0.$ Then you get a recurrence relation on the coefficients, bd agin get complexity when you have repeated roots. There just isn’t going to be an easy closed form.